# What is the name of the website that has the searchable linux kernel files?

Tags: linux-kernel

I don't mean where can I download the kernel. I don't mean kernel documentation either.

I mean I know there is a website where I can flip through/search through the source code of the linux kernel, well organized, without having to download anything onto my laptop. It's not github by the way.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel

Comment: via https://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHackingTools perhaps it's http://lxr.linux.no/ ?

Comment: Another fun one: http://www.makelinux.net/kernel_map/

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at https://sbexr.rabexc.org/
It is only in beta, but it’s a good cross-referencing kernel source browser, and you can select the exact kernel version you need. Latest is the default.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been using http://lxr.linux.no but it seems to be broken now. Maybe it is the website you were looking for.

It looks like the service is still available at https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean: https://livegrep.com

The you can not only read also can do complex search:

```
Query: /* 1/exp(5sec/1min)


torvalds/linux:v4.19:include/linux/sched/loadavg.h
#define FSHIFT      11      /* nr of bits of precision */
#define FIXED_1     (1<<FSHIFT) /* 1.0 as fixed-point */
#define LOAD_FREQ   (5*HZ+1)    /* 5 sec intervals */
#define EXP_1       1884        /* 1/exp(5sec/1min) as fixed-point */
#define EXP_5       2014        /* 1/exp(5sec/5min) */
#define EXP_15      2037        /* 1/exp(5sec/15min) */
```